# Add the attribute of a 1 to many relationship on the many side too?

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, erd

I want to make an ER diagram involving a 1 to many relationship. Should I add the attribute of the relationship on the N side too? And if possible write the correct ER diagram.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a simple example of many people working in one department with a constraint that a single person can work only in one department. That makes department connected to people in a one-to-many fashion.

The simplest way to represent this is to add the primary key of you department table as a foreign key in your people table.

The schema will look something like this

```
DEPARTMENT (dept_no, dept_name, dept_location,....)
PEOPLE (p_no, dept_works, p_name, p_dob,....)
```

Where, dept_works in PEOPLE table is the foreign key that references the dept_no Primary key in the DEPARTMENTS table. This way you can store the ID of the department for each person in which he/she works.